# Trying to create a dataset of images using the webcam, but cv2.imwrite saves only empty images

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, image-capture, webcam-capture

I am trying a facial recognition code and collecting a data set for my code. However, the images captured in my data set are  of 0 bytes. Please tell me where I am going wrong.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 
import pickle


cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0);
faceDetect = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml');

id = raw_input('Enter user Name')

sampleNo = 0;

while(True):

    ret,img = cam.read();
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = faceDetect.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5);
    for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
        sampleNo = sampleNo+1;
        cv2.imwrite("dataSet/"+str(id)+"_" +str(sampleNo)+ ".jpg", gray[y:y+h, x:x:w])
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w, y+h), (0,0,0), 2)
        cv2.waitKey(100);
    cv2.imshow("Face", img);
    cv2.waitKey(1);
    if(sampleNo > 20):
        break;
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You're using `:` instead of `+` here: `gray[y:y+h, x:x:w]`. It should be `gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]`

Comment: Wow, thank you. That was irrevocably stupid of me! @Zindarod